# Execute command or transfer files to remote windows machine

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, rpc, remote-access

What I'm actually looking for is the equivalent off ssh connection in windows environment. As per requirement, my controller machine can connect to remote machine with username password using some kind of utility/protocol such as ssh or telnet or rpc or tpc and using this session I can transfer files or execute command on remote machine. This connection execution must be done without any intervention from remote machine, i.e. I don't need to install any module or install any utility on remote machine or run any script.

My both controller and remote environment are windows.

Can someone suggest me python module or utility, using which I'll be able do this ?

I explore few option however I'm not sure if they are the best way to do so. Pleas provide your thoughts on this too.

1. connect using psexec utility through popen.
2. using socket to communication channel, however I'm not sure if I can execute any command using this channel.
3. making use of Telnet. but I didn't explore the python module to make telnet connection and execute command.
4. using module such as  Pyro or rpyc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: i wish there is a implementation of scp for windows. Why dont you use ftp?

Comment: after a quick search, this will be helpful for you;
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/how-to-use-ftp-in-python/

Comment: @eiki I can use ftp just for file transfer but how would I execute and command or run any executable on remote machine?

Comment: sorry i missed the point. Afaik you can't run any executables from ftp connection. If you insist to stick with Windows, look for ssh for windows.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the pexpect module. It can be used for ftp, ssh ...
[pexpect doc](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/)